# Jest can't find .env.local for MONGO_URI

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, jestjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app using a MongoDB. I just added Jest for testing. When I run the first test I get the following error:

Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local

```
  4 |
  5 | if (!MONGODB_URI) {
> 6 |     throw new Error('Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local');
    |           ^
  7 | }
```

I do have a file `.env.local` that has a MONGODB_URI and it works when I run my app locally and and on prod.

This is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Home from '../../pages/index';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<Home />', () => {
    it('should render Home', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
        console.log('wrapper :', wrapper.debug());
    });
});
```

My jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    clearMocks: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
        '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
    },
    preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb'

};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Jest won't automatically pick up the env vars you have in `.env.local`. You'll need to set them when running your tests, or point Jest to the .env file you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

The `.env.local` is not loaded in the test environment, as you expect tests to produce the same results for everyone.

But you can still use environment variables for tests.

#### 1. Option

You can use a `env.test` file and add the following to a globalSetup.js file

```js
...
import { loadEnvConfig } from '@next/env'

export default async () => {
  const projectDir = process.cwd()
  loadEnvConfig(projectDir)
}
...
```

Make sure to setup the `globalSetup.js` file in the `jest.config.js` file:

```js
...
globalSetup: ['<rootDir>/test/globalSetup.js'] // path to file
...
```

When you run your tests there should be a log in the console:

```sh
    Loaded env from C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\nextjs\.env.test
```

More information here: [Next.js Environment Variables Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

#### 2. Option

You can use the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for the test env with the env.local file.

Add this in your jest-setup.js file:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: '.env.local' })
```

Comment: Option 2 works like a charm :)

Comment: in the path which is here ".env.local", can I set dynamic path based on the value set in .env file which actually relies which env currently it's running - because my project can run on any environment and I don't know which env to trigger at run time

Answer (score 1):

in nextJS, I use `.env.test` for test environment.

Comment: Yes, it worked without issue

Answer (score 0):

you will have to pass `setupFiles` option  in the `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ['env.local.config file'],
}
```

to use `MONGODB_URI` in the tests